# `this` isn't set to current object in monkey patched prototype method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, monkeypatching, react-test-renderer

I am trying to monkey patch an object created by `react-test-renderer` to add a .findById(testID) method, but inside the object I can't access other methods on the object.
Here is the relevant code in my test file.

```
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'

beforeEach(() => {
  //...

  tree = renderer.create(<MyComponent {...props} />).root

  Object.getPrototypeOf(tree).findById = function (testID) {
    this.findAll((el) => {
      return el.props.testID === testID
    })
  }
})

it('does something', () => {
  const component = tree.findById('myTestId')

  // ...
  expect(/* something */)
})
```

Instead of having the `findAll` method on `this` it seems to be the global object. Why is this? I thought that if I call a method on an object that `this` will be set to that object when I use an old-school `function` function.

Comment: Try to change function (testID) { to arrow  (testID)=> {

Comment: With arrow function I get `TypeError: _this.findAll is not a function`

Comment: Try tree.findall

Comment: import * as TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';   TestRenderer.ReactTestInstance.findall

Comment: Figured it out. I think it was something wrong with the debugger. Here is the correct function: `Object.getPrototypeOf(tree).findById = function findById(testID) {
    return this.findAll((el) => {
      return el.props.testID === testID
    })[0]
  }`